# Jenkins: mercurial scm: clean=false is not working as expected

Tags: jenkins, mercurial, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

**EDIT:** It seems as if the MercurialSCM plugin hardcodes the `update` to use the `--clean` option. See [this line](https://github.com/jenkinsci/mercurial-plugin/blob/5c6297af895dddc2eee75647c9d13786226a38fc/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/mercurial/MercurialSCM.java#L728). Anyone have any ideas what's the idea?

I have the following checkout step in my Jenkinsfile:

```
checkout([
        scm: [
            $class: "MercurialSCM",
            source: "ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/xxxxx/${repo}",
            credentialsId: "jenkins",
            revision: params[branch] ? params[branch] : "default",
            subdir: (repo == "f8_root") ? "" : "aarch64/${repo}",
            clean: false,
        ],
        poll: true,
])
```

The argument for `clean` is set to `false`. But, the plugin still seems to issue an `update` with the `--clean` option. From the logs:

```
[Pipeline] checkout
[f8_fw] $ hg showconfig paths.default
[f8_fw] $ hg pull --rev feature/test-framework
pulling from ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/doblesc/f8_fw
no changes found
[f8_fw] $ hg update --clean --rev feature/test-framework
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like `--clean` is hardcoded into the MercurialSCM Jenkins plugin.

See OP for the [link to the culprit code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/mercurial-plugin/blob/5c6297af895dddc2eee75647c9d13786226a38fc/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/mercurial/MercurialSCM.java#L728).

I have opened up a [ticket on Jenkins jira](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-55870).